# Can't connect to local SQL Server 2005 when plugged into corporate network

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

This has me stumped. I setup SQL Server 2005 on my development laptop and connected an ASP.NET application to it the other day at home. It is configured with SQL Server Authentication, Remote access is enabled for both TCP/IP and named pipes along with a static IP. Both my application and SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express could connect to it fine.

Then when I came into work today my application can not connect to the local database. Mgmt Studio can connect fine. I get the following error on connection.Open():

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)"

This is the connection string:

```
Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Initial Catalog=Community;User ID=sa;Password=password;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Packet Size=8192
```

Here is the weird part if I disconnect from the network (unplug the lan cable) I can connect to the database. And after that initial connection is made I can even plug back in the cable and continue to query the database. If I restart my application once it is blocked.

I've disabled Windows Firewall completely and have exhausted my options. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ".\SQLEXPRESS" instead of "localhost\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: No luck. Both .\SQLEXPRESS and {machine-name}\SQLEXPRESS fail the same way.